# How to add data of changing sell in google sheets if it adds through API

Tags: javascript, api, google-sheets, zapier

A have a table in Google Sheets, where I get data from website contact form through API. I need to add a data for each submission (row of table) in a separate column. I tried fuction onEdit, but it works only for manual changes and it doesn't work if sells changing through API. 
What should I change?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var idCol = e.range.getColumn();
  var idRow = e.range.getRow();
  if (idCol == 1 && sheet.getName() == "Лист1") {
    var Value = e.range.offset(0, +2).getValues(); // Смотрим что в ячейке с лева на 2
    if (Value == "") {
      var vartoday = getDate();
      var varnow = getTime();

      sheet.getRange(idRow, 3).setValue(vartoday);
      sheet.getRange(idRow, 4).setValue(varnow);
    }
  }
}

// Returns YYYYMMDD-formatted date.
function getDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  today.setDate(today.getDate());
  //return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'PST', 'yyyy.MM.dd');
  return Utilities.formatDate(today, "GMT+03:00", "yyyy.MM.dd");
}

function getTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  today.setDate(today.getDate());
  //return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'PST', 'yyyy.MM.dd');
  return Utilities.formatDate(today, "GMT+03:00", "HH:mm");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Question:

Can I run triggers, like [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite), if a cell was modified with [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest)?

### Answer

No, because script executions and API requests **do not** cause triggers to run, take a look on [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions)

> Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For example, calling [FormResponse.submit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#submit) to submit a new form response does not cause the form's submit trigger to run.